# Protecting routes with getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have been trying a few ways to protect a route when a user is not authenticated but so far I've been struggling with it.

The most recurring problem when trying to authenticate from getServerSideProps was that I'd often encounter a `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, so I've been trying to not redirect from there and set a `redirect` boolean so I can redirect from the client. Problem is that now I get a error that states `No router instance found. you should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.` even though I'm (I think) in the client.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: ApiRoutesTypes) {

  const cookie = parseCookies(ctx);

   if (!testCookie.autho) {
     const redirectLogin = true;

     return { props: { redirectLogin } };
   }

  const query = {
    text: 'SELECT fk_users_id FROM tokens WHERE token = $1 AND status = true',
    values: [cookie],
  };
  const userId = (await db.query(query)).rows[0].fk_users_id;
    ...

  return { props: { userId } };
}
```

```js
export default function Homepage({redirectLogin }){
  const router = useRouter();

  
  if (redirectLogin) {
    router.push('/login');
  }

    ...

}
```

Is it possible to solve this? If not, what would be the best approach to redirect if all my pages do heavy use of getServerSideProps but also need to be authenticated?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to use protected routes and redirect the user to login page-

Use a function to set Inital Props for a page-
Now if the while calling the function pass if Page is protected or not.

```
export const authInitialProps = isProtectedRoute => ({
  req,
  res,
  query: { userId }
}) => {
  const auth = req ? getSessionFromServer(req) : getSessionFromClient();
  const currentPath = req ? req.url : window.location.pathname;
  const user = auth.user;
  const isAnonymous = !user;
  if ( isProtectedRoute && isAnonymous && currentPath !== "/signin") {
    return redirectUser(res, "/signin");
  }
  return { auth, userId };
};
```

here isProtectedRoute  will tell if route is protected or not.
if so and also the user in not logged in or not.
if not- Then.

> Redirect the user to a new page i.e signin.

If logged in- Then

> Pass the authentication data to page.

Now to check for user logged in or not ?

1. Server Side Checking-

```
export const getSessionFromServer = req => {
  if (req.user) {
    return { user: req.user };
  }
  return {};
};
```

2. Client Side Checking-

```
Use cookies or local storage, whatever is being used by you.
To check for the login.
```